# Doubt on a proof that the regularity of a curve is independent of the parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

Let $\gamma:I\subseteq R\rightarrow R^3$ be a curve, we define a re-parametrization of $\gamma$ as the curve $\alpha=\gamma\bullet \psi$, where $\bullet$ is the normal composition and $\psi$ is an increasing diffeomorphism betweem intervals. Now, the proof that the regularity of the curve is independent from the parametrization goes like that: let $\alpha=\gamma\bullet \psi$ be a re-parametrization of a regular curve $\gamma$, deriving this expression we get $\alpha'(s)=\gamma'(\psi(s))\psi'(s)$. Because $\psi^{-1}(\psi(s))=s$ so $(\psi^{-1})'(\psi(s))\psi'(s)=1$, then $\psi'(s)\ne0$ and so $\alpha$ is a regular curve itself. What I don't understand in the proof is how $(\psi^{-1})'(\psi(s))\psi'(s)=1$ implies that $\psi'(s)\ne0$ . I tried deriving the expression: $[\psi^{-1}(\psi(s))]'=(\psi^{-1})'(\psi(s))\psi'(s)$. Now, we know that $\psi^{-1}(\psi(s))=1$ so its derivative is $0$. How to connect things and get the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will assume you forgot to mention $\gamma$ is regular) The reparametrization $\alpha$ is regular iff $\alpha' \neq 0$. The proof uses the chain rule to claim $\alpha'(s) = \gamma'(\psi(s))\psi'(s)$. Therefore we have:

$$\alpha'(s) = 0 \iff \gamma'(\psi(s)) = 0 \text{ or } \psi'(s) = 0$$

Now, $\gamma' \neq 0$ everywhere, so the only option is that $\psi'(s) =0$ for some $s$. Using the chain rule again on $\psi^{-1}((\psi(s))= s$ yields $(\psi^{-1})'(\psi(s))\psi'(s) = 1$. If $\psi'(s)$ were 0 this could not be equal to one, and the result follows.

Another easy proof that $\psi^{-1} \neq 0$ is that it is a diffeomorphism hence $(\psi^{-1}(s))' = \frac{1}{\psi'(s)}$ should be a continuous function, which would clearly be impossible if $\psi'(s) = 0$.
Towards the end of your question you seem to have mistaken $\psi^{-1}((\psi(s))= 1$ (it is actually equal to $s$ as we've shown in the last paragraph).

Comment: Thanks, I made some mistakes and should re-study the proof after this answer to get things clear.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(\psi^{-1})'(\psi(s))$ and $\psi'(s)$ are real numbers whose product is nonzero, each must be themselves nonzero.